# using jQuery in Safari Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, userscripts

I am trying to make a simple Safari 5 Extension that just injects a custom javascript. Any ideas how can I make use of jQuery in this custom script, please? I only know it's possible, because it is mentioned on one of WWDC videos, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: do you need to use jquery in your injected script or your global html file?

Answer (score 6):

You can include jquery.js as a "start script". Your regular script (as an "end script") will see it.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that if you don't need to keep jQuery updated, just copying the source code of jQuery into your extension's code base should work.